# How i can use sed or another to replace specific string in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

i am back after some users try to put negatives to all my post just with the bad intetion i can't post any question anymore. Well after of that, to the point.

I need help to edit a Makefile, to be more specific the Makefile from "mupen64plus-ui" -> https://github.com/robalni/mupen64plus-ui

The Original Line :

```
INCPATH       = -I. -isystem /usr/include/SDL2 
-isystem /usr/local/include/mupen64plus
 -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++
```

I Need :

```
INCPATH       = -I. -isystem /usr/include/SDL2 
-isystem "$TARGETDIR/include"
 -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++
```

You notice i just need to change a very specific detail and reaplace with the content i had on a variable on my script, right now that is the line 18 for that Makefile can find the files :
m64p_common.h, m64p_types.h, m64p_frontend.h, m64p_config.h

Needed to finish the compilation without errors.

And the another thing i need to understand is the follow lines :

```
LFLAGS        = -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-O1
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -lquazip5 -lSDL2 -lmupen64plus -ldl -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Network -lQt5Xml -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

When i try to compile, the output showme can't find "lmupen64plus" i think is searching for the file "libmupen64plus.so.2" in /usr/lib64 , but never can find there because i not compile the emulator and his file for system, just to a very specific prefix on another place.

Well i don't had any idea how i can indicate to the Makefile to search too in "$TARGETDIR/lib" for find that library can compile without errors.

If you want or need check entire script, had a lot of spanish text comment, you can do it visiting -> https://pastebin.com/mxwxHc6P

Well i hope someone can help me with the mupen64plus-ui part of Makefile to finish my macro script to download, compile & install it.

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in a single post. Write different questions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part's easy. Not sure why you want `sed` instead of just editing by hand.

```
sed -i "bak" -e 's#/usr/local/include/mupen64plus#"$TARGETDIR/include"#' Makefile
```

You are on the track for the second part. Include the search path you want like:

```
LFLAGS        = -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-O1
```

becomes:

```
LFLAGS        = -L/usr/lib64 -L$TARGETDIR/lib -Wl,-O1
```

Be sure `$TARGETDIR` is defined prior to using it in your Makefile. If `TARGETDIR` has spaces in it then you need to include it quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much i use the follow

```
sed -i "Makefile" -e "s#/usr/local/include/mupen64plus#$TARGETDIR/include#" Makefile

sed -i "Makefile" -e "s#LFLAGS        = -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-O1#LFLAGS        = -L/usr/lib64 -L$TARGETDIR/lib -Wl,-O1#" Makefile
```

Thanks solve the edition, but i can't compile yet, still the output is

```
g++ -L/usr/lib64 -L/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Linux/Emulador/mupen64plus/64Bits/lib -Wl,-O1 -o mupen64plus main.o cheatparse.o common.o core.o mainwindow.o error.o plugin.o sdl.o settings.o configcontrolcollection.o keyspec.o aboutguidialog.o cheatdialog.o cheattree.o configeditor.o downloaddialog.o gamesettingsdialog.o inputdialog.o logdialog.o pluginconfigdialog.o settingsdialog.o emulation.o emuthread.o glwindow.o vidext.o osal_dynamiclib.o romcollection.o thegamesdbscraper.o gridview.o listview.o tableview.o clickablewidget.o treewidgetitem.o qrc_mupen64plus.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_aboutguidialog.o moc_cheatdialog.o moc_cheattree.o moc_configeditor.o moc_downloaddialog.o moc_gamesettingsdialog.o moc_inputdialog.o moc_logdialog.o moc_pluginconfigdialog.o moc_settingsdialog.o moc_emulation.o moc_emuthread.o moc_romcollection.o moc_thegamesdbscraper.o moc_gridview.o moc_listview.o moc_tableview.o moc_clickablewidget.o   -lquazip5 -lSDL2 -lmupen64plus -ldl -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Network -lQt5Xml -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.5.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lmupen64plus
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
Makefile:420: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'mupen64plus'
make: *** [mupen64plus] Error 1
```

well LD can't find -lmupen64plus, but i don't understand what i need to solved it

Comment: your `sed` command's a little different than what i was expecting.  first, the `-i "Makefile"` is creating a backup file called "Makefile.Makefile".  second, you are interpreting `$TARGETDIR` in your shell instead of in your Makefile. That's OK if that's what you were expecting/wanting. is `mupen64plus` in `/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Linux/Emulador/mupen64plus/64Bits/lib` ?  Because it looks like that's the file you are trying to compile.  Maybe take out "` -lmupen64plus`"?

Comment: When i use "bak" the output says can't find file called "bak", i put on the script to change directory to search in the $TARGETDIR, well the project is a "GUI" for Mupen64plus well i try taking out -lmupen64plus

Well not work, because search functions inside the library

Comment: Well searching i found this is and old problem for the project -> https://github.com/robalni/mupen64plus-ui/issues/1 . Well i need to close this question.

Comment: Well searching i found this is and old problem for the project -> https://github.com/robalni/mupen64plus-ui/issues/1 . Well i need to close this question.